# iOS Simulator version of iPhone not showing console.log output with errors

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, safari-web-inspector

I'm not 100% sure how to explain this.

I have a really annoying issue! I'm trying to debug a new website in iOS. It works fine on all desktop browsers (including Safari on the Mac).

I have the debugger enabled (Web Inspector), and it shows the console.log output, network requests etc all fine WHEN the page work.

However, I have an issue where every couple of loads the page doesn't work. I don't get any error messages, it just "doesn't do anything". I see the network requests for some of the JS file, but then it just stops (it should load another 10 or so).

There is no error message in "Console", so I'm not sure where this problem is coming from :/

I've ordered a test phone to try it out in the "real world" (linked to the Safari Debugger), but I still think I'm going to have the same problem.

Is there something else I need to do? I'm on Safari 11.0.3, OSX 10.13.3 and Simulator version 10.0

I've literally been searching around for a solution for the last 2 hours, so I'm really hoping someone can help me.

Comment: I have the same problem with Safari 12.0.3 and Simulator 10.2. And I don't even see the network log. I have the same issue if I connect a device to my computer and trying to inspect it.

Comment: I installed Safari Technology Preview and using that instead, solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can install Safari Technology Preview.